# Defining an ElasticSearch mapping for a particular entity with FOSElastica

Tags: php, symfony, elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

I'm currently trying to use FOSElastica and I'm having trouble with the configuration. I want to use a serializer with most of my entities, but I want to specify the mapping for a particular entity, how could I do this ?

I've tried defining the "properties" options but with the "serializer" option defined it just seems to ignore it.

I'd want to do something like this, but the "table_content" properties is just ignored.

```
fos_elastica:
    serializer: 
        serializer: jms_serializer
    clients:
        default: { host: localhost, port: 9200 }
    indexes:
        table_content: 
            types: 
                table_content: 
                    properties:
                        id: ~
                    persistence: 
                        driver: orm 
                        model: TAMAS\AstroBundle\Entity\TableContent
        astonomical_object:
            types:
                astonomical_object:
                    serializer:
                        groups: [astonomicalobject]
                        serialize_null: true
                    persistence:
                        driver: orm
                        model: TAMAS\AstroBundle\Entity\AstronomicalObject
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, in fact FOSElastica does indeed recognize the type when you map it by hand in the config file, it was a bad understanding on my part. But it was still tedious since I had objects within objects within objects...

So, after some time I found a solution to my problems : [Dynamic templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/dynamic-templates.html) and [Index templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/indices-templates.html)

I actually had trouble with ElasticSearch not recognizing some types of fields (like date or geo_point), so I forced them for specifically named fields with help of templates.

If you want an example of my configuration in FOSElastica ([doc is here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle/blob/master/doc/templates.md)) :

```
fos_elastica:
    serializer: 
        serializer: jms_serializer
    clients:
        default: 
            host: localhost 
            port: 9200
    index_templates: # https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/indices-templates.html
        base_template: # this is a custom name for the index template
            client: default
            template: "*" # this is where you define which indices will use this template
            types:
                _doc: # this is where you define which types will use this (_doc stands for every type/documents)
                    dynamic_templates: # https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/dynamic-templates.html
                        dynamic_date_template: # this is a custom name for the dynamic field template
                            match_pattern: regex
                            match: created|updated|tpq_date|taq_date
                            mapping:
                                type: date
                        dynamic_location_template:
                            match: location
                            mapping:
                                type: geo_point
```